# My Tensorflow code always prints different values

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

When I runned my code four times, it printed four different results.It was so strange. I traied to write a VGG16 net, and I used the trained variables from "https://mega.nz/#!YU1FWJrA!O1ywiCS2IiOlUCtCpI6HTJOMrneN-Qdv3ywQP5poecM" . I think no matter which image inputed into my VGG, it should print the same result.

Here is my code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def convolution(layer_name, inputs, out_channels, trainable=True, activation_function=None):
    with tf.variable_scope(layer_name):
        conv_kernel_weight = tf.get_variable(
            trainable=trainable,
            name="weight",
            shape=[3,3,inputs.get_shape()[-1].value, out_channels],
            dtype=tf.float32,
            initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
        )
        conv_kernel_bias = tf.get_variable(
            trainable=trainable,
            name="bias",
            shape=[out_channels],
            dtype=tf.float32,
            initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0)
        )
        conv_data = tf.nn.conv2d(inputs,
                                 conv_kernel_weight,
                                 strides=(1,1,1,1),
                                 padding="SAME",
                                 name="conv")
        Wx_plus_b = tf.nn.bias_add(conv_data, conv_kernel_bias)
        if activation_function is None:
            return Wx_plus_b
        else:
            return activation_function(Wx_plus_b)

def max_pool_2x2(name, inputs):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(inputs,
                          ksize=[1,2,2,1],
                          strides=[1,2,2,1],
                          padding="SAME")

def connect_pool_and_fc(pool_inputs):
    shape = pool_inputs.get_shape()  #1,7,7,512
    length = shape[1].value * shape[2].value * shape[3].value
    outputs = tf.reshape(pool_inputs, [-1, length], name="reshape_pool_fc")
    return outputs

def full_connection(name, inputs, out_channels):
    with tf.variable_scope(name):
        fc_kernel_weight = tf.get_variable("weight",
                                           shape=[inputs.get_shape()[-1].value, out_channels],
                                           initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
        b = tf.get_variable('bias', shape=[out_channels], dtype= tf.float32)
        fc_kernel_bias = tf.Variable(b,
                                     name="bias")
        activation = tf.nn.relu_layer(inputs, fc_kernel_weight, fc_kernel_bias, name="activation")
        return activation

def vgg(image_RGB):
    data_flow = image_RGB  #input an RGB image or a batch
    data_flow = convolution("conv1_1", data_flow, 64, True, tf.nn.relu)
    data_flow = convolution("conv1_2", data_flow, 64, True, tf.nn.relu)
    data_flow = max_pool_2x2("pool_layer1", data_flow)

    data_flow = convolution("conv2_1", data_flow, 128, True, tf.nn.relu)
    data_flow = convolution("conv2_2", data_flow, 128, True, tf.nn.relu)
    data_flow = max_pool_2x2("pool_layer2", data_flow)

    data_flow = convolution("conv3_1", data_flow, 256, True, tf.nn.relu)
    data_flow = convolution("conv3_2", data_flow, 256, True, tf.nn.relu)
    data_flow = convolution("conv3_3", data_flow, 256, True, tf.nn.relu)
    data_flow = max_pool_2x2("pool_layer3", data_flow)

    data_flow = convolution("conv4_1", data_flow, 512, True, tf.nn.relu)
    data_flow = convolution("conv4_2", data_flow, 512, True, tf.nn.relu)
    data_flow = convolution("conv4_3", data_flow, 512, True, tf.nn.relu)
    data_flow = max_pool_2x2("pool_layer4", data_flow)

    data_flow = convolution("conv5_1", data_flow, 512, True, tf.nn.relu)
    data_flow = convolution("conv5_2", data_flow, 512, True, tf.nn.relu)
    data_flow = convolution("conv5_3", data_flow, 512, True, tf.nn.relu)
    data_flow = max_pool_2x2("pool_layer5", data_flow)

    data_flow = connect_pool_and_fc(data_flow)
    data_flow = full_connection("fc_layer1", data_flow, 1024)
    data_flow = tf.nn.dropout(data_flow, keep_prob=1.0, name="drop_out")
    data_flow = full_connection("fc_layer2", data_flow, 3)
    return data_flow

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1,224,224,3], name="x")
    logit = vgg(x)
    logit = tf.nn.softmax(logit)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        init_op = tf.group(
            tf.global_variables_initializer(),
            tf.local_variables_initializer()
        )
        sess.run(init_op)
        params_load = np.load(".\\vgg16.npy", encoding='latin1').item()
        # print(params_load)
        for key in params_load:
            if key not in ['fc6', 'fc7', 'fc8']:
                with tf.variable_scope(key, reuse=True):
                    for subkey, data in zip(('weight', 'bias'), params_load[key]):
                        sess.run(tf.get_variable(subkey).assign(data))

        image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.read_file("D:\\MelanomaDetectionDemo2.0\\valid_data\\ISIC_0000004.jpg"), channels=3)
        image = tf.expand_dims(image, [0])
        image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [224,224])
        print(sess.run(logit, feed_dict={x: image.eval()}))
```

Help me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

[tf.set_random_seed](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/set_random_seed) should make this deterministic. Otherwise variable initialization is random.

Or are you hoping that all of the variables get assigned from that `npy` file? If so, don't call the initializers and you'll get an error for the variables which weren't assigned.